# Find edge points of numpy array for kmeans centroids initialization

Tags: arrays, numpy, initialization, k-means, centroid

I am working on implementing a kmeans algorithm in python.
I am testing out new ways of initializing my centroids and wanted to implement it and see what affect it would have on the cluster.

My idea is to select datapoints from my data set in a way that the centroids are initialized to edge points of my data.

Simple example 2 attribute example:

Lets say this is my input array

```
input = array([[3,3], [1,1], [-1,-1], [3,-3], [-1,1], [-3,3], [1,-1], [-3,-3]])
```

[image: Graph example of input]

From this array I would like to select the edges points which would be [3,3] [-3,-3] [-3,3] [3,-3]. So if my k is 4, these points would be selected

In the data that I am working with has 4 and 9 attributes and around 300 data points in my data set

note: I have no found a solution to when k <> edge points but if k is > edge points I think I would select these 4 points and then try to place the rest of them around the center point of the graph

I have also thought about finding max and min for each column and from there try to find the edges of my data set but I don't have an idea of an effective way of identifying the edges from these values.

If you believe this idea will not work I would love to hear what you have to say.

Questions

1. Does numpy have such a function to get the indexes of data points on the edge of my data set?
2. If not, how would I go at finding these edge points in my data set?

Comment: What do you mean by edges points?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, by edge points I mean data points that in the data set that include maximum/minimum of a attribute making them the furthest from the center.

I updated the question with a image that I hope explains this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scipy` and pair-wise distances to find how farther each one is from another:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
p=pdist(input)
```

Then, use `sqaureform` to get p vector into a matrix shape:

```
s=squareform(pdist(input))
```

Then, use numpy `argwhere` to find the indices where values are max or are extreme, and then look up those indices in the input array:

```
input[np.argwhere(s==np.max(p))]

array([[[ 3,  3],
        [-3, -3]],

       [[ 3, -3],
        [-3,  3]],

       [[-3,  3],
        [ 3, -3]],

       [[-3, -3],
        [ 3,  3]]])
```

Complete code would be:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
p=pdist(input)
s=squareform(p)
input[np.argwhere(s==np.max(p))]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is in the direction of what I wanted.
I am trying out your code but receiving some issue, will continue with this approach

arr[argwhere(p==max(p))] leads to a value error:
|
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: is arr equal to input?

Comment: yes: arr = array([[3,3], [1,1], [-1,-1], [3,-3], [-1,1], [-3,3], [1,-1], [-3,-3]])

Comment: works for me with arr. earlier, missed the closing bracket for argwhere. edited. check now.

Comment: Wish I had another way to share this. This is the code I am working with and the error received commented below: [shared code](https://codeshare.io/G6xZ1p)

Comment: Okay, I see the issue, same variable name for squareform and pdist, if i do p=pdist(arr);s=squareform(p);arr[argwhere(s==max(p))] it works! I updated your comment and accepted. Thank you so much!

Comment: Done, needed to add more changes so I could change it. added summary code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159818/discussion-between-thor-and-sharatpc).